# Return Modified Fields in LinqDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, linqdatasource

I have a `LinqDataSource` like this one :

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="linqDSUsers" runat="server" 
     ContextTypeName="Repository.BBDatabaseDataContext" 
     Select="new (UserID,FirstName,LastName)" TableName="Users">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

**How can I convert it into this :**

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="linqDSUsers" runat="server" 
     ContextTypeName="Repository.BBDatabaseDataContext" 
     Select="new (UserID,FullName = FirstName + LastName)" TableName="Users">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select="new (UserID, FirstName + LastName As FullName)"
```